# Gunicorn queue: run only 1 request per unique id, with multiple workers

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm using `Gunicorn` in combination with `Python Flask` to serve a API. It returns a prediction, based on the input data which is sent as `json` in the body of the request. The `json` contains a `session_id`. It can take up to about 10 seconds to get a response from the API (it's calculating a complicated ML model).

I want `gunicorn` to handle up to 4 requests in parallel, but only max 1 request per unique `session_id`. So if a given session already made a request, which is still busy, and a new request for the same session is made, this request needs to wait until the previous request with the same `session_id` is finished.

I can of course somehow "lock" the request for a given `session_id`, based on some table with all `session_ids` which have active requests. But this means that one of the workers is simply "sleeping" and waiting until another request is finished. This is not the kind of solution I'm looking for.

My question: is there a way to tell gunicorn to serve FIFO, but with max 1 request per unique id. Hence take the next request in the queue if gunicorn is busy handling another request with the same `sessions_id`?

Minimal working flask api:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    input_dict = request.get_json()
    print('id %s'%(input_dict['id']))

    time.sleep(10)

    responses = jsonify({'prediction':42})
    responses.status_code = 200

    return (responses)
```

Input example:

```
{
  'session_id': 123,
  'some_data': 456
}
```

`gunicorn` serves the API using 4 workers:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 main:app --workers=4
```

Comment: Would it be ok to just reject requests while there is already a prediction in progress for a given session ID? Otherwise requests will just block the workers.

Comment: This means that the service which makes the requests must be made "clever", rather than the queue of gunicorn. It would work of course if we just reject, but not exactly an answer to the question.

Comment: Did you have any conclusions about the approach?